# Zend_Tool, create db-table.from-database doesn't work in project (module not found)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a Zend Framework project with an existing database, so I'd like to create models based on the tables that I have in my database. I can run zf commands from the command-line and in Netbeans just fine, for example generating controllers/forms works just fine. However, when I want to create the model from the database using the command

```
zf create db-table.from-database application force-overwrite
```

it gives me this error:

```
A models directory was not found for module application.               

Zend Framework Command Line Console Tool v1.12.1
Details for action "Create" and provider "DbTable"
  DbTable
    zf create db-table name actual-table-name module force-overwrite
    zf create db-table.from-database module force-overwrite
```

The same thing happens when I try it with

```
zf create db-table.from-database Application force-overwrite
```

Just to clarify: the models directory DOES exist in my project folder. I'm assuming I have to enter application because it's the module I'm working in (the default one).

My database connection is fine too, since I can execute queries just fine. Has anyone got an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this feature, but 'application' is not a module. If you don't want it to scan a specific module folder I would guess you leave that parameter out. What happens if you just call `zf create db-table.from-database force-overwrite`?

Answer (score 0):

As with most things the problem can be as simple as a case sensitive and/or miss spelled directory name/path.
I don't believe this problem can be solved without interaction/emulation.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen `zf create db-table.from-database` work in any circumstances. However if you want to try the netbeans command that should work is `-m default` ('default' is the module, add -f for force overwrite) the resulting command will look like: `zf create db-table.from-database -m default`.

Personally I just use the `zf create db-table` command to create just the db-table models I need.

This command would work `zf create db-table users users -m admin -f` where `-m admin`(the -m does seem to be required) is the module and `-f` indicates force over write. The first `users` is the name of the class (Application_Model_DbTable_Users, Users.php), the second `users` is the actual name of the database table.

I don't know what you're expecting as far a model goes, what you're going to get is something very similar to:

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name    = 'users';
}
```

This a very important class when using the Zend_Db component but if you're new to ZF it may be a little confusing.